# How can Replace String _ Aggregate function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sql query taking too much time in excution .

**My Code**

```
Select @output_direction = STRING_AGG(IsNull(b.Text,a.Item),' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SrNo)
from string_split(@direction,' ') a 
left join [dbo].[Sign]  b 
on a.Item = b.Token and b.Language = 'E'
```

This method taking more time . How can I reduce excution time ? Is change string_agg is possible and usefull for reduce time ?

Comment: This is obviously **not** MySQL. Maybe SQL Server (MS SQL)?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh  Using ms-sql

Comment: Added, and your question will hopefully get the correct attention.

Comment: Can you [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)?

Comment: Do you have any solution??